# Converting byte[] to object in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, serialization, memorystream, binaryformatter, directcast

I have a byte array, for example:

```
Dim byteArray(10) as Byte

byteArray(0) = 1
byteArray(1) = 2
byteArray(2) = 3
...
byteArray(9) = 10
```

and I am trying to convert it into an object but without success. I have read a lot of posts here about on how to do it so I have below function:

```
Public Shared Function ByteArrayToObject(ByVal arrBytes As Byte()) As Object

    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        Dim binForm As New BinaryFormatter()
        ms.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length)
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Dim obj As Object = DirectCast(binForm.Deserialize(ms), Object)

        Return obj
    End Using

End Function
```

but when performing the DirectCast I am getting an exception saying, more or less (translated from spanish):

```
"SerializationException was unhandled: End of sequence reached before terminating analysis".
```

Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: The byte sequence `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` doesn't sound like a serialized instance of `Object`.  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Did you try `CType(byteArray, Object)`?

Comment: Why don't you create a structure or class that is ***serializable***?

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of bytes:

```
Dim byteArray(10) as Byte

byteArray(0) = 1
byteArray(1) = 2
byteArray(2) = 3
...
byteArray(9) = 10
```

Which is this byte stream:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

But you *don't* have a *serialized object*.  Which is what your code assumes:

```
Dim obj As Object = DirectCast(binForm.Deserialize(ms), Object)
```

That stream can't be de-serialized into an instance of `Object` because, well, it isn't a serialized instance of `Object`.  But this is (or at least is on my machine in my test):

> 0 1 0 0 0 255 255 255 255 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 1 0 0 0 13 83 121 115 116 101 109 46 79 98 106 101 99 116 0 0 0 0 11

Basically, you can't just de-serialize *anything* into an instance of an object.  It has to be an actual serialized version of that object.